# Pandas: Group Data by column A, Filter A by existing values of column B

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm new to pandas and want to create a new dataset with grouped and filtered data.
Right now, my dataset contains two columns looking like this (first column with A, B or C, second with value):

```
A 1 

A 2

A 3

A 4 

B 1

B 2

B 3 

C 4
```

--> now I want to group by the keys of the first column (A,B,C) , and show only the keys, where the values 1 AND 2 exist.
So that my new data set looks like:

```
A 1

A 2

B 1

B 2
```

Until now, I'm only able to print everything but I don't know how to filter:

```
for name, group in data.groupby('keys'):
   print(name)
   print(group)
```

I'm thankful for any help!

Comment: I THINK what you want is to filter the dataframe so that you only have rows where the column 'value' is 1 or 2? If so, have you tried something like data.loc[ (data['value'] == 1) | (data['value'] == 2) ]

Comment: Yes, almost. But for example if C has the values 1 and 4, I don't want C to be shown as a result

Comment: Oh I see, that wasn't clear from your question to be honest, but I have posted an answer, hope it helps

Comment: Sorry, that's true. I realized it too late

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = df.loc[(df['col2'] == 1) | (df['col2'] == 2)]
```

And then filter the groups that dont contains both values:

```
df = df.groupby('col1').filter(lambda x: any(x['col2'] == 2))
df = df.groupby('col1').filter(lambda x: any(x['col2'] == 1))
```

Example:

```
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    A     2
2    A     3
3    A     4
4    B     1
5    B     2
6    B     3
7    C     4
8    C     1
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    A     2
4    B     1
5    B     2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now all the Column_A values are printed, where the columnB value is 1 or 2, **but** I want to print only these rows, where both values exist for the columnA value (A,B,C)

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
l=[1,2]
print df[df['col2'].isin(l)]
```

For this problem you really don't need groupby,

If you want try this also,

```
df.groupby('col1').apply(lambda x:x[x['col2'].isin(l)]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but here's still the problem as well, that all columns of A where printed, where either 1 or 2 exists. But I want to print only these, where both values exist. Is there anything I could add?

Comment: @User123 - I didn't understand your comment (But I want to print only these, where both values exist), can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to groupby.
Just use :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_a': ['A','A','A','A', 'B','B','B', 'C'], 'col_b': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]})
df.loc[(df.col_b == 1) | (df.col_b == 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter out all keys with values '1' or '2':

```
data = data.loc[ (data['value'] == 1) | (data['value'] == 2) ]
```

Then filter out only the keys you want to see:

```
data = data.loc[ (data['key'] == 'A') | (data['key'] == 'B') ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
For this example it works, but is there a way to expand it to a bigger example?
I have a list with many different values instead of A, B and C and want to know, which of these keys contain the value 1 AND 2 (at the same time) in column B