# Pandas: How to sort group data by datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

as an extension to the question [Pandas: Group Data by column A, Filter A by existing values of column B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51377779/pandas-group-data-by-column-a-filter-a-by-existing-values-of-column-b) my data has now a datetime for each value, which looks like this:

```
2011-10-01 20:24:21
```

**EDIT**: at first the time data had the right structure, but was from dtype: object. I changed it by using:

```
dataset['Date']= pd.to_datetime(dataset['Date'])
```

Is this correct?

So at the moment, I have a dataset which structure looks like this:

```
_Group, Value, Date:_

A 2  **2011-10-01 20:24:21**

A 1   **2011-10-01 20:27:21**

A 3   **2011-10-01 20:25:21**

B 1   **2011-10-01 20:23:21**

B 2 **2011-10-01 20:26:21**

B 3 **2011-10-01 20:24:21**

B 3 **2011-10-01 20:25:21**
```

I want to order the values of each group depending on the datetime.

--> I already checked, that the datatime has the dtype: datetime, but when I try to order it (ascending), not all the datetimes are in the right order within a group.
When I tried to order just the dates, then it works fine.

I tried the following code:

```
  dataset.sort_values('Date').sort_index(level='Group')
```

As a result, the dates are in the right order, but sometimes they aren't regarding the hours and seconds.
Where is my mistake?

I'm thankful for any help!

Comment: Try ````sort_values(['Group', 'Date'])````?

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort using multiple levels:

```
dataset.sort_values(['Group', 'Date'])
```